# Integrate CKEditor in ADF12c Popup

Tags: ckeditor, oracle-adf

Am trying to integrate CKEditor in a ADF popup which is in a page fragment using JSP Tag Libraries.
Am using JDeveloper 12.13 version.
Here is the code am using in a popup which is in a subform.

```
<cke:editor basePath="/PLS/js/" editor="editor1"  value="Type Here"/>
```

Am getting below error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find component to stream
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.streaming.StreamingDataManager.submit(StreamingDataManager.java:519)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DocumentRenderer._encodeStreamingResponse(DocumentRenderer.java:4047)

Getting this exception with different Content Delivery modes(immediate, lazy)  for popup. I have also tried declared ADF RichText Editor and replacing it with CKEDitor replace tag.

Does anyone has idea why CKEDitor is not working in ADF Popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a popup i have implemented CKEditor in a separate task flow and used that as a region in my main page by invoking that task flow as inline-popup dialog. This resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Does your var rt1 and rt2 return any values or are they undefined? To search for components in ADF page , you should use javascript as defined in links [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/groundside/pattern-for-obtaining-adf-component-id-for-javascript) and [here](http://www.techartifact.com/blogs/2013/05/find-adf-faces-components-in-page-by-javascript-findcomponent.html#sthash.POwyjTni.dpbs) .

You can also refer the oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24382_01/web.1112/e16181/af_arch.htm#ADFUI10039) for using ADF client side Architecture.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have started using JSP Tag library instead of a javascript code. Please check my updated code.